# How to separate numbers from words, chars and any other marks with whitespace in string

Tags: c#, string, variables, text, replace

I'm trying to separate numbers from words  or characters and any other punctuation with whitespace in string wrote them together e.g. string is:

```
 string input = "ok, here is369 and777, and 20k0 10+1.any word.";
```

and desired output should be:

```
 ok, here is 369 and 777 , and 20 k 0 10 + 1 .any word.
```

I'm not sure if I'm on right way, but now what I'm trying to do, is to find if string contains numbers and then somehow replace it all with same values but with whitespace between. If it is possible, how can I find all individual numbers (not each digit in number to be clearer), separated or not separated by words or whitespace and attach each found number  to value, which can be used for all at once to replace it with same numbers but with spaces on sides. This way it returns only first occurrence of a number in string:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "here is 369 and 777 and 15 2080 and 579"; 
        string resultString = Regex.Match(input, @"\d+").Value;

        Console.WriteLine(resultString);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

output:

```
369
```

but also I'm not sure if I can get all different found number for single replacement value for each. Would be good to find out in which direction to go

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If what we need is basically to add spaces around numbers, try this:

```
string tmp = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<a>[0-9])(?<b>[^0-9\s])", @"${a} ${b}");
string res = Regex.Replace(tmp,   @"(?<a>[^0-9\s])(?<b>[0-9])", @"${a} ${b}");
```

---

Previous answer assumed that words, numbers and punctuation should be separated:

```
string input = "here is369 and777, and 20k0";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"([A-Za-z]+|[0-9]+|\p{P})");
foreach (Match match in matches)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
```

To construct the required result string in a short way:

```
string res = string.Join(" ", matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value));
```

Comment: The print statement should be Console.Write("{0} ", match.Groups[1].Value);

Comment: @inquisitive_mind I did not want to make it more complicated by adding logic to avoid ending space.

Comment: @inquisitive_mind Anyway, added a Linq-based oneliner.

Comment: @AlexD Hello, yes good way, but I got two problems here in my case, first, It separates not only numbers from everything else, but also separates punctuation marks from words. And another one is, as I want separate numbers from everything, but same time I want keep everything else in string,  with this code, I'm not sure why, but I lost "+" sign on the output.

Comment: @MDaruwalla Punctuation mark is requested to be separated: `here is 369 and 777 , and 20 k 0`. There is a space before `,`. Could you give the failing sample(s)? What is the input, and what is desired output.

Comment: @AlexD Yes because the number before the comma. Probably it is not enough good example of the string. Now edited to `ok, here is 369 and 777 , and 20 k 0`   and string in code below, I have not changed it, because it is given as sample to search, but not as desired result. And still not sure why "+" sign is lost

Comment: @MDaruwalla Updated. Is it now closer to what you need?

Comment: @AlexD yes it is closer, but I edited sample string once again, to show you what happens with number, so if string is: `ok, here is369 and777, and 20k0 10+1.any word.`  and output should be  `ok, here is 369 and 777 , and 20 k 0 10 + 1 .any word.` now result is: `ok, here is 369 and 777 , and 20 k0 10 +1 .any word.` single number 1 is not separated from sign "+". So if reason of this is my phrase "not each digit in number to be clearer" here I meant that I don't need find each digit in separate number, but any number must be separated, single or multi-valued

Comment: @AlexD Ok so except separation of single number 1 from sign "+", all this solutions, include previous one, which is deleted,  answers on my question and i'm going to mark this solution as answer, because it is easy now figure out with `1 +1` which should be `1 + 1` if you look at the   edited string sample

Comment: @MDaruwalla The issue was that `+` was a part of two matches, `1+` and `+1`. I updated the post to cover this case.

Comment: @AlexD Well as I said question is actually almost solved and marked as answer, but last code, again gives not complete result `ok, here is 369 and 777 , and 20 k 0 10 + 1.any word.` now number 1 is separated from "+" but merged with dot

Comment: @MDaruwalla Ahh, it was pretty much the same, instead of `1+1` pattern, `+1+` was the problem this time. Perhaps a simple fix would be to run twice, first time to add spaces after, and second - before numbers. Is it OK now?

Comment: @AlexD yes as I said it was easy to solve it with last examples and your help, so thank you support, and yes I did the same   simply combined the two previous codes,  but last answer is complete with 100% desired output

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right path. Regex.Match only returns one match and you would have to use `.NextMatch()` to get the next value that matches your regular expression. `Regex.Matches` returns every possible match into a `MatchCollection` that you can then parse with a loop as I did in my example:

```
string input = "here is 369 and 777 and 15 2080 and 579";

        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

This Outputs:

```
369
777
15
2080
579
```

Comment: Hello, yes seems like I can somehow figure out this way too, but the solution above answers to my the question completely

Answer (score -1):

This provides the desired output:

```
string input = "ok, here is369 and777, and 20k0 10+1.any word.";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"([\D]+|[0-9]+)");
foreach (Match match in matches)
    Console.Write("{0} ", match.Groups[0].Value);
```

[\D] will match anything non digit. Please note space after {0}.

Comment: Hello, seems like it is same answer as above, it is good solution but not for my case, because It separates not only numbers from everything else, but also punctuation marks from words. And as I want separate numbers from everything, but same time I want keep everything else in string, but for some reason I lost "+" sign on the output with this code.